# How to get VBA click button on page?

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, scrape, getelementsbytagname

I have problem as my code doesn't execute .click command!

```
Sub getdata()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://app.scheduleonce.com/Home.aspx"

With ie
While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
End With
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document

Set dfrom = doc.getElementById("TxtDateFrom")
dfrom.Value = "Dec 01, 2017"
Set dto = doc.getElementById("TxtDateTo")
dto.Value = "Jan 31, 2018"

Set btn = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(12)
btn.Click


With ie
While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
End With

Dim mt As String
For IDn = 1 To 100
mt = doc.getElementById("rowID_" & IDn).innerText
Sheets(1).Range("a" & IDn) = mt
Next IDn
End Sub
```

and here is troubled line from HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Go" class="btn" style="" onclick="DateFilter();">
```

So in general, most of code does work and it goes on designated page, it does change calendar values to ones I want, it copies data from page to excel, but...

It doesn't click the button after changing date range so change is never applied!

I've checked which Tag "input" is and it is 12th (tried 13 too just in case)!

How to click button and apply changes of dates?

Here is HTML of DATE FROM box:

```
 <div id="datediv" style="">                               
 <div class="filderItems">
 <div class="homeFilters">
 <div class="boldText">
 From:
 <input id="TxtDateFrom" style="" class="calendertbs" onclick="OpenDatePicker('CalDivFrom', 'TxtDateFrom'); blur(); return false;"
                                            readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
 <span onclick="OpenDatePicker('CalDivFrom', 'TxtDateFrom');  return false;" style="cursor: pointer">
 <img id="CalDivFrom" src="//cdn.scheduleonce.com/images/calender_icon.jpg" alt="" />
 </span>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="filderItems">
 <div class="homeFilters ml10">
 <div class="boldText">
```

It seams that with my VBA code Ive only changed TXTboxes but not actually the date so it only look like Ive selected certain data range but actually I didn't!

Here is PRNTSCR. Text is changed but actually date isn't picked from picker and probably that way not applied!

[image: One date is in textbox but another in data picker]

How can I select date in Data picker?

Comment: This appears to require you to have an account with ScheduleOnce?

Comment: @QHarr, yes I do have and it does auto login. No problem there. Even if it would make a problem Ill just toss in vba to log in.

Comment: It gets stuck as when it change the dates it simply doesnt click the button to execute change

Comment: When I manually click it (dates remains changed by VBA), everything is fine and it does apply date change

Comment: try `.fireevent("click")`

Comment: I hoped, but... I get Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument! Still, it change the dates but not proceed with clicking the button! I'm clueless!

Comment: Are there `<form>` tags in the html, you may need to `document.forms(0).submit`

Comment: I just realized that only textboxes are changed for dates and actual date range is not applied. Ill paste HTML...

Comment: And no luck with form submit. It still doesn't apply and filter by date range I've set! Maybe the problem is with Date picker?